# getting memory allocation at ActivityIndicator in Iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Here I'm gettimg memory allocation problem at activity indicator and my code is:

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.title=@"Release Details";
        contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
        contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.view = contentView;
        [contentView release];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320,1500);
        containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        webView = [ [UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"background1.png"]];
        webView.delegate = self;        
        [containerView addSubview:webView];
        CGRect activityViewframe = CGRectMake(20,8,20, 20);
        progressInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:activityViewframe];
        progressInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
        progressInd.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
```

UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
            [containerView addSubview:progressInd];
            [progressInd startAnimating];
            progressInd.hidden = NO;
            [progressInd stopAnimating];
            [self.view addSubview:containerView];
            isFetch=YES;
        }
        return self;
    }

```
-(void) displayInProgressRightBarButton
{
    UIView* rightBarButtonView = [ [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270,5,45, 35)];
    [rightBarButtonView addSubview:progressInd];
    UIBarButtonItem* buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithCustomView:rightBarButtonView];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
    [rightBarButtonView release];
    [buttonItem release];
}
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self displayInProgressRightBarButton];
    [progressInd startAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [progressInd stopAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

Also I released the progressInd in dealloc eventhough it showing memory allocation at

```
progressInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:activityViewframe];
```

in init.

can anyone help me to solve this.

Anyone's help will be much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (and should) release it right after adding it to the container view:

```
[containerView addSubview:progressInd];
[progressInd release];
```

The same for the container view itself:

```
[self.view addSubview:containerView];
[containerView release];
```

The containing view will retain the subview for you, so you can release it right after adding it.